# VS Code with Jupyter's interactive window: How to change the syntax colors in Python Interactive window (some text is unreadable on dark themes)?

Tags: themes, jupyter, visual-studio-code, python-interactive

I'm using VS Code with the Jupyter's Python Interactive window so that I can run individual cells and get the output, figures etc. in the Python Interactive window.

However, some of the colors are unreadable on darker themes, for example **see the blue and red words in the example below**.

Changing the theme does not change the colors in the Python Interactive window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer to your question unfortunately, but I have found the built in dark themes remain legible in the python interactive window. You may find that you have to restart vs code for the theme change to occur. This is a screen shot while using the included dark+ theme.

[image]

Comment: Weird, this looks different from mine with the default Dark+ theme, which looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/nC7wVGS.png (the blue text is impossible to read, red color for strings doesn't make sense and so on...)

Comment: Restarting VSCode and reloading the window made the "import" parts a bit more readable, but the errors are still unreadable (the blue and red parts): https://i.imgur.com/NPNSvhB.png

Comment: Yes, it seems the cell output text is not great - I think the appearance settings might need to be exposed in the extension. One similar workflow you might be interested in as a workaround is the VSnotebooks extension.

Answer (score 0):

There's a helpful thread on customizing Jupyter colors on this VS Code Python github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3773.

Given a recent download of the python extension, you can go to settings > user settings, then search for 'data science', and adjust things there. My issue was error cells of the interactive window not matching the default dark theme.

Before:
[image]

I applied this solution (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3773#issuecomment-478073314), and now:

[image]

I'm using VS Code `1.33.0`, with Python extension v `2019.3.6352` on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Change the theme to vs-code dark theme/default-themes and change back to your custom theme.

Notebook will retain the vs codes defaults themes.

Only a workaround to get a pretty theme in notebook. Cant change to custom theme.

That would make this.

[image: Notebook Theme before switching the theme.]

to this

[image: Notebook Theme after switching theme to default vscode dark mode then to custom theme]

If you are wondering,
My Vs Code theme is Bluloco Dark theme