# Visual Studio interactive window unreadable highlighted error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Recently, Visual Studio started highlighting errors in the interactive window, which makes them unreadable:

[image: Error highlighted]

How can I remove or change the highlight color? I looked around SO but can't find any of the settings mentioned (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55578823/3284713)).

I am using the standard VS dark theme. Other dark themes didn't solve the issue

Comment: This recently started happening for me too.  Since this is in the default dark mode, it seems like this ought to be considered a bug.

Comment: @Chad [Rio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70893209/3284713) points to the right direction to solve the issue. Unfortunately I did not have the time to find the right setting to be modified. You might want to start from there

Comment: Same thing for me... it only happens in docker containers that I "Attach to Visual Studio Code" though. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [rioV8's instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70893209/3284713), I added the following to my settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.ansiYellow": "#1e1e1e"
}
```

Replaces the awful yellow with the same background color as the interactive window in the default dark mode. Works for VSCode v1.63.2.

Answer (score 4):

- start the Developer tools: **Help > Toggle Developer Tools**
- use the top left button and locate the text in the interactive window
- in the elements tab you can see which terminal colors it uses
- customize that terminal color for that particular [workbench color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#integrated-terminal-colors) in your [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color)
- you can limit that change for a particular theme

I'm not using VSC 1.63 at the moment, so I can't give you the specific name.

Comment: Adding the following to my settings.json worked: ```"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
          "terminal.ansiYellow": "#1e1e1e"
    }```

Comment: The above comment worked for me too. (@bsauce)

Answer (score 0):

you can install python indent for highlighting your code this plugin is standard you can past this extension `kevinrose.vsc-python-indent`and dark theme for vscode `dhedgecock.radical-vscode` in search bar in VScode this extension use for python and vscode.